# cherrypy: respond to url that includes a dot?

Tags: python, url, cherrypy

Is there a way to get CherryPy to respond to a url that includes a period, such as `http://some/base/path/oldscript.py` ? I have a number of old CGI scripts that were called like that, and I'm trying to roll them into a nice pretty CherryPy web app - but I don't want to break all the bookmarks and the like that still point to the CGI scripts. Ideally the same method would respond to the url regardless of if it has a .py or not.

Comment: Could somebody explain why my question was down voted? I'm not insulted, but if I did something wrong/asked the question poorly, I would like to know what or why so I can do better in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out using an _ in the method definition works as a dot/period. This does mean I have to have two function definitions if I want to be able to call it either with or without the .py, but since I can easily call the one function from the other, this is a minor quibble.

Comment: Don't call; alias. Just add foo_py = foo under def foo.